# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net

After trying to publish my asp.net website I have encountered the error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9a188c8922137c6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried clearing up the Temporary Folder but still the same issue occurs. Any help with this? I can't even debug my own web site because of the error above. By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I am running on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me and a colleague was able to resolve this issue. It turns out that we are using Newtonsoft.Json without our knowledge and that we are also using the wrong version. Thanks for helping out everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You must check `path property` of your `assembly Newtonsoft.Json`, verify that you have assembly in this location

I suggest you to set `Local Copy` to `false` and define common repository for all assemblies.

Comment: Hello Frederique, how do i those things? I'm pretty much new with ASP.Net

Comment: On your project in solution Visual studio, expand Reference node, and you find all called assemblies by your project, select your Newtonsoft.Json , right click on asselbly and define properties such as local copy to false , and set path of downloading

Comment: Hello again Frederique, I have checked your solution and I dont have any Newtonsoft.Json. Can I just download it and add on my project?

Comment: Hi Frederique, I have downloaded Newtonsoft.Json and tried setting the local copy to false but still same error occurred.

Comment: you must ensure that you have the good path on your deployment server

Comment: @GianIsTheName set Copy To Local to True.